# JSP user authentication and tracking

Tags: jsp, authentication, servlets

I will keep it simple, I have a simple website with two JSP pages, Main.jsp and Form.jsp, and a servlet for each.

In Main.jsp the user will enter a username and password, to which I will compare them to an SQL stored data, if data match I redirect the user to Form.jsp, if not then reload Main.jsp.

That's great and all, until I realized that anyone can type the URL of Form.jsp and have access to the page and skipping the first authentication page.

I am new to web development, what is the solution for this ?, is there some sort of session manager ?.

Not only do I want to control access to From.jsp, but I also want to know which user filled the form, instead of just any random user with a url to the form can fill it (Since Form.jsp directly updates an SQL table, I want to store the username of whoever updated the table alongside the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filters for this task.

http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful, a bit TL;DR, but I'll make sure I read it.

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime" That link is amazing, I read it in details and it is very helpful.
Your answer gets my vote.

Comment: Thank you, and you welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

After authenticating you probably need to store in users session some kind of token indicating that user was correctly authenticated. e.g.: UserId. Then for all other requests it should be checked whether this token is present. If it's not present then need to redirect user to login page. You could probably do the authenticated check in a ServletFilter

Comment: Where will this token be stored ?
Like a cookie or something ?

Comment: @AhmadLabibMansour it should be stored in users session. request.getSession()

Answer (score 0):

add filter entry in web.xml

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>ValidationFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>ValidationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>ValidationFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

and add class in your project

```
public class ValidationFilter implements Filter {
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
               chain.doFilter(new ValidatingHttpRequest( (HttpServletRequest)request ), response);
       }
   }
```

customize as per your requirment